# What does man eater upper mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, reservoir-dogs

In *Reservoir Dogs* (1992), Eddie is describing a woman named Lady E to his gang members while driving in
the car with them:

> Eddie: Anyway, Lady Ε, I mean, she was a **man-eater-upper**.
> Un-f*cking-believable. Εvery guy who ever laid eyes on her
> had to jack off to her at least once.

I understand the meaning of “man-eater,” but I’m not sure what
the “upper” part means.

What does man eater upper mean ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a conflation of two different phrases, *man-eater* and *eat up*.

To *eat up* means to consume all of something, it's often used by parents to encourage children to finish their vegetables. I.e. "If you don't *eat up* all of your veg, you don't get any dessert." The most common other time you'll encounter it is (usually women) using the phrase to describe cute children, "you're so cute I could just *eat you up*."

Changing it to "eater-upper" is merely turning that phrase into an adverb.

It takes the *man-eater* description to the next level, she doesn't just eat them, she eats them all.

Comment: another "*Tarantinoism*"... :)

Comment: Not an adverb, but an agent noun (phrase). This may be a Tarantinoism, but it has precedent in the common phrase “fixer-upper”, and no doubt there are others. It’s not unusual, in informal language, for [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs) to be modified in this way: something that really should only apply to the verb, like the agent suffix “-er”, is applied to another part of the phrase as well (or instead).